# unordered_map with IP address as a key

Tags: c++11, boost

I am trying to build a list of linked list in my application. The list will contains unique IP addresses,and for each IP addres I have a list of applications. I am trying to build it using unordered_map to take Boost::boost::asio::ip::address as a the key and std::list as value:

```
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

typedef int     ApplicationID;
typedef address IPAddress;
typedef list <ApplicationID> APP_LIST;
typedef boost::unordered::unordered_map <IPAddress, APP_LIST> USER_MAP;

USER_MAP user_map;
```

Later I try to get the list associated with an IP address as following:

```
APP_LIST *list = &user_map[ip];
```

But I get errors in the compilation, so could you please specify what's the problem?

1. Is it possible to use Boost:IPaddress as a key function?
2. Another question is it possible to use char[some_size] as a key value?

**Error Output:**

```
In file included from /boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:535:0,
                 from /boost/functional/hash.hpp:6,
                 from /boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:21,
                 from ipc_module.cpp:18:
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp: In member function ‘std::size_t boost::hash<T>::operator()(const T&) const [with T = boost::asio::ip::address, std::size_t = long unsigned int]’:
/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:331:55:   instantiated from ‘boost::unordered::detail::table_impl<Types>::value_type& boost::unordered::detail::table_impl<Types>::operator[](const key_type&) [with Types = boost::unordered::detail::map<std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::asio::ip::address, std::list<int> > >, boost::asio::ip::address, std::list<int>, boost::hash<boost::asio::ip::address>, std::equal_to<boost::asio::ip::address> >, boost::unordered::detail::table_impl<Types>::value_type = std::pair<const boost::asio::ip::address, std::list<int> >, boost::unordered::detail::table_impl<Types>::key_type = boost::asio::ip::address]’
/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:1192:26:   instantiated from ‘boost::unordered::unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A>::mapped_type& boost::unordered::unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A>::operator[](const key_type&) [with K = boost::asio::ip::address, T = std::list<int>, H = boost::hash<boost::asio::ip::address>, P = std::equal_to<boost::asio::ip::address>, A = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::asio::ip::address, std::list<int> > >, boost::unordered::unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A>::mapped_type = std::list<int>, boost::unordered::unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A>::key_type = boost::asio::ip::address]’
ipc_module.cpp:175:40:   instantiated from here
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:176:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘hash_value(const boost::asio::ip::address&)’
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:176:34: note: candidates are:
/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:708:33: note: template<class T> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const boost::shared_ptr<T>&)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:144:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(bool)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:144:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘bool’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:149:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(char)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:149:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘char’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:154:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(unsigned char)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:154:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘unsigned char’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:159:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(signed char)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:159:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘signed char’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:164:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(short int)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:164:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘short int’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:169:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(short unsigned int)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:169:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘short unsigned int’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:174:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(int)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:174:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘int’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:179:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(unsigned int)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:179:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘unsigned int’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:184:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(long int)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:184:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘long int’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:189:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(long unsigned int)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:189:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘long unsigned int’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:195:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(wchar_t)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:195:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘wchar_t’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:202:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(boost::long_long_type)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:202:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘boost::long_long_type {aka long long int}’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:207:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(boost::ulong_long_type)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:207:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘boost::ulong_long_type {aka long long unsigned int}’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:215:36: note: template<class T> std::size_t boost::hash_value(T* const&)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:308:24: note: template<class T, unsigned int N> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const T (&)[N])
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:314:24: note: template<class T, unsigned int N> std::size_t boost::hash_value(T (&)[N])
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:327:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(float)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:327:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘float’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:332:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(double)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:332:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘double’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:337:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(long double)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:337:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘long double’
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:321:24: note: template<class Ch, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::basic_string<Ch, std::char_traits<_CharT>, A>&)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:343:24: note: std::size_t boost::hash_value(std::type_index)
/boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp:343:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::asio::ip::address’ to ‘std::type_index’
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:54:17: note: template<class A, class B> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:63:17: note: template<class T, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:69:17: note: template<class T, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:75:17: note: template<class T, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:81:17: note: template<class K, class C, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:87:17: note: template<class K, class C, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:93:17: note: template<class K, class T, class C, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:99:17: note: template<class K, class T, class C, class A> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:105:17: note: template<class T> std::size_t boost::hash_value(const std::complex<_Tp>&)
/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:177:9: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
/boost/asio/error.hpp: At global scope:
/boost/asio/error.hpp:244:45: warning: ‘boost::asio::error::system_category’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
/boost/asio/error.hpp:246:45: warning: ‘boost::asio::error::netdb_category’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
/boost/asio/error.hpp:248:45: warning: ‘boost::asio::error::addrinfo_category’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
/boost/asio/error.hpp:250:45: warning: ‘boost::asio::error::misc_category’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: Might want to format your code, I know its a lot. Just be considerate please.

Comment: @Shrink I reduced the output, I believe the what I kept is enough.

Comment: It still isn't formatted correctly though. People seem to ignore questions that aren't properly formatted.

Comment: That’s not the entire error message…

Comment: @Petter I had it, but then another guy told me to reformat.

Comment: I see, The relevant part you removed is “error: no matching function for call to ‘hash_value(const boost::asio::ip::address&)’.”

Comment: @HA-AS So, why didn't you... reformat :)

Comment: @sehe thanks for reformatting :)

Comment: @HA-AS What's worse, I also answered for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I came up with after a brief inspection of the class interface for `ip::address`.

I would like to note that it's pretty wasteful to use. Especially if you happen to know that all addresses are ipv4, e.g. I'd prefer to key by `ulong` then.

```
namespace boost
{
    template <>
        struct hash<IPAddress>
        {
            size_t operator()(IPAddress const& v) const { 
                if (v.is_v4())
                    return v.to_v4().to_ulong();
                if (v.is_v6())
                {
                    auto const& range = v.to_v6().to_bytes();
                    return hash_range(range.begin(), range.end());
                }
                if (v.is_unspecified())
                {
                    // guaranteed to be random: chosen by fair dice roll
                    return static_cast<size_t>(0x4751301174351161ul); 
                }
                return hash_value(v.to_string());
            }
        };
}
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebbe7d03cd8a435a)**:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

typedef int                                                  ApplicationID;
typedef boost::asio::ip::address                             IPAddress;
typedef std::list<ApplicationID>                             APP_LIST;
typedef boost::unordered::unordered_map<IPAddress, APP_LIST> USER_MAP;

namespace boost
{
    template <>
        struct hash<IPAddress>
        {
            size_t operator()(IPAddress const& v) const { 
                if (v.is_v4())
                    return v.to_v4().to_ulong();
                if (v.is_v6())
                {
                    auto const& range = v.to_v6().to_bytes();
                    return hash_range(range.begin(), range.end());
                }
                if (v.is_unspecified())
                    return 0x4751301174351161ul;
                return hash_value(v.to_string());
            }
        };
}

int main()
{
    USER_MAP map;
    map.insert({ {}, {} });
}
```

Comment: +1, @sehe Thanks a lot for your answer, but my question why don't you use directly `return hash_value(v.to_string());`
And for my second question, is it possible to use char[some_size] as a key value in unordered_map?

Comment: @HA-AS 1st: efficiency (in fact I only used it as a "chicken" fall back in case I missed some kind of domain knowledge. You could replace that line with a `assert(!"unreachable")` if you are bold). 2nd: No, but you can if you write a hash function for it: [see on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfbc9797b8eec857)

Comment: @HA-AS Mmm. Actually, strike that. *[GCC accepted it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5398fd20e3ce864)*, but I think raw arrays don't work as map keys. So, favour `std::array` or `boost::array`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c51aca6d945d2d25

Comment: the problem I am trying to pass few arguments through shared memory, and my program is getting more and more complicated. And between the arguments is char[4], but after digging I found I need to use basic string from Boost

Comment: can you help me in a new problem? I am trying to find a value as following

`std::pair<IPAddress*, std::size_t> user_ip = managed_shm->find<IPAddress>("USER-IP");

USER_MAP::const_iterator got = user_map.find(user_ip.first);`


But I get the following error:


`ipc_module.cpp:147:75: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::unordered::unordered_map<boost::asio::ip::address, std::list<int> >::find(boost::asio::ip::address*&)’`

Comment: You can use std::array just fine.  Use boost IPC allocators with any container types. That should enable them to be put into shared memory

Comment: Oh somehow, my phone didn't show your last comment. Reading

Comment: Don't worry, I got your idea. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I recently came across the same issue while writing a game in c++17.

This is how I solved it:

```
struct endpoint_hash
{
    std::size_t operator()(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint const& ep) const noexcept
    {
        auto accum = std::size_t(0);
        auto combine = [&accum](auto&& arg) {
            boost::hash_combine(accum, arg);
        };

        combine(ep.port());
        if (auto&& addr = ep.address(); addr.is_v4())
        {
            combine(addr.to_v4().to_ulong());
        }
        else
        {
            combine(addr.to_v6().to_bytes());
        }
        combine(ep.port());
        return accum;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint, std::shared_ptr<game_client>, endpoint_hash> cache_;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you write a hash function for IPaddress.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me an example how to do that, for a non string data type

Comment: +1 for being correct in principle. I don't think it's generally helpful to provide a one-line answer. It's SO ettiquette to drop those nuggets of wisdom in a comment.